# How to send STX and ETX over sockets

Tags: vb.net

With VB.NET, i need to send to a tcp listener the following:

```
<STX>CODER<ETX>
```

I understand i need to send stx and etx but i don't know how to do this.

i have declared:

```
Public Const STX = &H2
Public Const ETX = &H3
```

and i try to send a string like this:

```
var = STX & "CODEX" & ETX
bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(var)
```

but it doesn't work

Can anyone give some help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&H2` and `&H3` (0x2 and 0x3) are the *character codes* for STX and ETX. They're just numbers, meaning your two constants currently contain the integers `2` and `3` respectively. For this reason your string literally results in `"2CODEX3"`.

You need to convert the character codes into actual `Char`s to be able to put them in a string. Since we can't do this with constants in VB.NET, we'll have to use read-only variables instead:

```
Public ReadOnly STX As Char = ChrW(&H2)
Public ReadOnly ETX As Char = ChrW(&H3)
```